# Swapping a header image on scroll with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple question (I hope). I have a site with a sticky navigation bar at the top. All I'm trying to do is swap a header image so when you're on the top of the page it's the full image, but when you start scrolling it switches to another image with a bit of a fade transition.

It feels like something like this should work, but it doesn't. I'm not a programmer so I'm sorry if this is dumb and I appreciate any assistance:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.headerimg').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.headerimg')
            .css({'background-image: url(PATH TO SMALL LOGO)'})
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $('.headerimg')
            .css({'background-image: url(PATH TO FULL LOGO)'})
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then in the main HTML I just have the image being pulled in via a plain div

```
<div class="headerimg"></div>
```

Comment: I hope you set a height to `.headerimg`

Comment: "It feels like something like this should work, but it doesn't." Please be more specific, or provide a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, you have some errors in your code, so it won't work even if you are doing it right:

```
{'background-image: url(PATH TO SMALL LOGO)'}
```

should be:

```
{'background-image': 'url(PATH TO SMALL LOGO)'}
```

Since you are passing an object to jQuery `css` function. Also, you may want to add a fixed property to keep the header on top. What you are trying to achieve is known as sticky header, and you can find plenty examples on the web. I made a litte Fiddle with a minimal example of your code, but can (should) be improved to get better performance and cross-browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/tomsarduy/38hun91z/

**Note**: You could see the problem in the browser console:

- Windows (Ctrl+Shift+J)
- Mac (Cm+Shift+i)

Comment: Basically your fiddle is doing what I want. My site is in Wordpress though and based on Foundation so the sticky header portion of things is already working correctly, It's just the logo image within the header I want to change when you scroll. I've tried copying your code over to my site and making the necessary image link changes and it just doesn't work. I don't know if there are conflicting scripts or what is going on. I'm just getting blank space where the header image used to be. Unfortunately the site is currently on a local server so I can't even send a link to it.

Comment: Try the console to see if you get any error? If not, you would have to show more relevant code :/